# Power supply module is being powered by the arduino

Tags: arduino, power-supply, stepper-motor

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fcBsa2.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

i started a project to try and pilot a 28BYJ-48 5v stepper motor with its ULN2003 board from an arduino Nano, along with some LEDs and buttons.

I've been told that powering the motor from the arduino was a bad thing, so i took an Elegoo Power MB v2 power supply board.(it seem you can't buy it separately, so i could only find few references : https://www.hackster.io/ingo-lohs/power-supply-module-3-3v-and-5v-d58dbe). I plugged its DC Jack with a 12v 2A power supply (it was for a hard drive i think), and i got now several concerns :

- the chips on the elegoo gets hot! after 5~ minutes, it will stop working and go on and off as it cools and heats up again. The arduino doesn't however. I've sticked on little heat dissipators but it's not enough.
- When the arduino is plugged through USB, the status LED on the power supply is being lit, even with all its inputs unplugged (!!!)
- At first, the status LEDs on my motor are all off, but when i use it, 2 won't turn off even i stop rotating the motor.

[Parts](https://i.imgur.com/0SqvTlL_d.jpg?maxwidth=640&shape=thumb&fidelity=medium)

the supply jumpers are set to 5v, the arduino's Vin is plugged to the +, the gnd to the - of the left part, and the motor's board are plugged the same way to the other side.

how can i fix this? thanks

Comment: 1) provide a **full** schematic of how everything is connected. 2) An Arduino can easily work from the 5V DC provided by a USB connection so the fact that LEDs light up when the USB is connected **is perfectly normal**. 3) That supply board is only for **low currents**, a stepper motor is **not** low current. You're asking too much from this board so it gets hot and luckily switches itself off before it destroys itself. Improvement suggestion can only be given **after** you show how all modules are connected.

Comment: so, what now ? should i bypass the board and connect the motor directly to the 12v DC ?

Comment: Why do you still ask for advise when I clearly mentioned: *provide a full schematic of how everything is connected.* and *Improvement suggestion can only be given after you show how all modules are connected* We don't do "I connected the aaa to the bbb and the xxx to the yyy" we use schematics here. A clear drawing on a piece of paper will do.

Comment: Steppers should not be run with a voltage regulator, but rather by feeding *several times* the rated voltage into a chopping driver which regulates current.

Comment: When you say 2 LEDs won't turn off. Do they stay on after you stop the motor or are they alway stuck on?

Comment: @RaphaelP hey! thank you for your answers they're very useful. Yeah the LEDs stays on after i stop it, when i plug the arduino in they're blank

Comment: But do they turn off at any time while the motor is turning? Or are they stuck?

Comment: i wish i could send you a video, but it's like: when i plug the arduino (4*blank), when it's rotating (4*red, but actually two red at time changing really fast), and when i stop moving, two stay stuck

Comment: You could change your code to power off the stepper when it's stopped; the library should be able to do that. But having two LEDs on in the end is not a problem. You're just holding the motor position. Inefficient, but OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, first some basic checking.

A quick search for that motor specs gives varying info, but coil resistance seems to be 35 Ohm worst case. You could try measuring it with a multimeter (motor disconnected from circuit). That rating would give a current draw of 142 mA per coil / 285 mA with two coils on. Seems to be within the 700 mA advertised rating for your supply board and also your main power supply.

Also, that simple stepper motor can be driven through a voltage regulator. There's no specialized driver, chopper, etc. It's just a ULN2003 acting as a low side switch for each coil.

So...

> the chips on the elegoo gets hot! after 5~ minutes, it will stop working and go on and off as it cools and heats up again. The arduino doesn't however. I've sticked on little heat dissipators but it's not enough.

You're probably drawing too much current from the board. Try measuring motor current with a multimeter. It could be a result of a program bug/mistake.

> When the arduino is plugged through USB, the status LED on the power supply is being lit, even with all its inputs unplugged (!!!)

You're backfeeding the supply board. You could try adding a diode between the supply board and the Arduino (which would drop it's voltage as a side effect) or simply disconnect it from the supply board before plugging in the USB, assuming it's just used for programming.

> At first, the status LEDs on my motor are all off, but when i use it, 2 won't turn off even i stop rotating the motor.

Two coils on could be a valid state for that kind of motor, albeit not efficient since that, being a geared motor, can probably hold it's position even powered down.

Here's what I'd do:

- Double check the digital connection between Arduino and motor board. Verify that you're setting the right outputs on code.
- Modify your program such that you step the motor very slowly. Check the LEDs on the motor board. They should progress in a well behaved manner. No LED should be always on or always off. There could be two adjascent LEDs on, but never three, nor two spaced apart.
- With the motor stopped but powered, check the current going into it's board with a multimeter.

Comment: effectively, from the time i started, i changed the library used and touched the cables. but i also changed the supply from a 12v 2A dc to a 5v 2A dc and after 10mins, nothing has heated up yet

Comment: ok, thanks to you all's fixed! i reset the digital pins to low when the motor stops and voila. for the backfeeding (i didn't knew this word), i try adding a diode but it didn't solved the problem

Comment: Was the diode between Elegoo's "5v Out" and Arduino's "Vin" (directed towards the Arduino)? Did the circuit work with the diode and without USB?

Comment: Yes, i used a IN4004. Don't worry, i consider my problem solved